PostgreSQL combining output
with type as (
  select
                A.AREA_CODE || '-' || SUBSTR(A.DIAL_NUMBER,1,3) || '-' || SUBSTR(A.DIAL_NUMBER,4) ph,
                A.SOURCE_RECORD_OID,DESCRIPTION
        from
                tel A,
                tclient B
        where
                A.SOURCE_RECORD_TABLE = 'ASSO'
                and B.OID = A.poid and DESCRIPTION in ('Work Cell','Personal Cell','Work Phone','Home Phone'))
select distinct CA.userid,
        Cep.EMPLOYEEID,
        CA.GIVEN_NAME as firstName,
        CA.FAMILY_NAME as lastName,
        CA.MIDDLE_NAME as middleName,
        NVL(CA.BUSINESS_EMAIL_ADDRESS ,
        CA.PERSONAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS) EMAILADDRESS,
        case when type_client.DESCRIPTION = 'Work Cell' then type_client.ph end BUSINESSMOBILE,
        case when type_client.DESCRIPTION = 'Personal Cell' then type_client.ph end PERSONALMOBILE,
        case when type_client.DESCRIPTION = 'Work Phone' then type_client.ph end BUSINESSPHONE,
        case when type_client.DESCRIPTION = 'Home Phone' then type_client.ph end PERSONALPHONE
        from type type_client,
        GTT_TIMECARDEMP P,
        assoc CA,
        cepos cep
        where cep.employeeid = p.supervisorid
        and cep.userid = CA.userid
        and CA.OID = type_client.SOURCE_RECORD_OID;

The output of above query :
  firstname  | lastname | middlename |         emailaddress          | businessmobile | personalmobile | businessphone | personalphone
------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------
 a          | b        |            |                               |                | yyy-xxx-0121   |               |
 a          | b        |            |                               | yyy-xxx-0121   |                |               |
 a          | b        |            |                               |                |                |               | yyy-xxx-0121
 b          | c        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-4869   |               |
 d          | e        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-2299   |               |
 f          | g        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-0496   |               |

expected output
if an employee has all types of phone numbers then it should come in single row or if he/she as more than one phone number then it should get as single row
   firstname  | lastname | middlename |         emailaddress          | businessmobile | personalmobile | businessphone | personalphone
--+------------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+---------------
  | a          | b        |            |                               | yyy-xxx-0121   | yyy-xxx-0121   |               | yyy-xxx-0121
  | b          | c        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-4869   |               |
  | d          | e        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-2299   |               |
  | f          | g        |            |                               |                | xxx-xxx-0496   |               |



You want a pivot operation. And, please please read this. https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

In the outer query, you can group by the initial fields, then get a min() in each phone number field. Or you can move your case statements to the CTE and do the pivot suggested by O. Jones above.

Your rows are multiplied because each phone number comes as a separate row, which gets joined independently to its target. As already pointed out by O. Jones in the comments, you can pivot those before the join.
You can use an aggregate filter clause for that:
with type as (
  select concat_ws('-',A.AREA_CODE,SUBSTR(A.DIAL_NUMBER,1,3)
                                  ,SUBSTR(A.DIAL_NUMBER,4)) as ph
        ,A.SOURCE_RECORD_OID
        ,DESCRIPTION
  from tel A join tclient B 
    on     A.poid       = B.OID
   and A.SOURCE_RECORD_TABLE = 'ASSO'
   and DESCRIPTION in ('Work Cell','Personal Cell','Work Phone','Home Phone') )
,type2 as (
  select SOURCE_RECORD_OID,
         min(ph)filter(where DESCRIPTION = 'Work Cell')     as BUSINESSMOBILE,
         min(ph)filter(where DESCRIPTION = 'Personal Cell') as PERSONALMOBILE,
         min(ph)filter(where DESCRIPTION = 'Work Phone')    as BUSINESSPHONE,
         min(ph)filter(where DESCRIPTION = 'Home Phone')    as PERSONALPHONE
   from type
   group by SOURCE_RECORD_OID )
select distinct CA.userid,
        Cep.EMPLOYEEID,
        CA.GIVEN_NAME as firstName,
        CA.FAMILY_NAME as lastName,
        CA.MIDDLE_NAME as middleName,
        NVL(CA.BUSINESS_EMAIL_ADDRESS ,
        CA.PERSONAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS) EMAILADDRESS,
        BUSINESSMOBILE,
        PERSONALMOBILE,
        BUSINESSPHONE,
        PERSONALPHONE
from type2 as type_client 
join assoc as ca          on type_client.SOURCE_RECORD_OID = ca.OID
join cepos as cep         on cep.userid = ca.userid
join GTT_TIMECARDEMP as p on cep.employeeid = p.supervisorid;


You can replace a sequence of || concatenations with one concat(), and give it all elements you want concatenated. If you're using a delimiter, you can use concat_ws() and pass it as the first argument. An bonus feature of that is that || will nullify the whole string if it gets a single null, while these functions will skip the null and keep the rest.
Ignore this point if you're using Amazon Redshift, which is usually the case when you tag PostgreSQL but use things like NVL() (regular PostgreSQL doesn't have it). Redshift doesn't have concat_ws(), and its concat() only accepts 2 arguments.

Explicit JOIN syntax is recommended over the old style, comma separated FROM lists with implicit joins constructed out of WHERE conditions.

Unquoted identifiers are folded to lowercase. By mixing when you use upper and lower case letters in them, you decrease readability and risk name mismatch errors, if someone or something starts double-quoting them.


